# How to make prev/next buttons visible when using minDate/maxDate in jQuery UI datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am making only the next 90 days selectable with jQuery UI datepicker 1.8.12.

```
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({ 
        minDate: '+1',
        maxDate: '+90',
        onClose: function() {
            if ($('#datepicker').val() != '') {
                $('#submitForm').submit();
            }
        } 
    });
```

When the datepicker comes up, the prev/next arrows in the top left and top right are invisible. My users are being confused about how to change the month in the datepicker. How do I make those prev/next arrows visible? I tried *start* and *flick* themes.

Comment: Which browser are your users using? I just tried [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/XdwfV/) with your code and the buttons are visible with either theme...

Comment: I'm using a custom jQuery UI build that only has dialog and datepicker. I will try with a non-custom one. Maybe that's the issue.

Comment: The answer is: Make sure you have the images available that jQuery UI needs for those buttons, like:
`url("images/ui-icons_0073ea_256x240.png")`
Only including the jQuery CSS is not sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the images available that jQuery UI needs for those buttons, like: `url("images/ui-icons_0073ea_256x240.png")`

Only including the jQuery CSS is not sufficient.